# NodeMCU/ESP8266 with 2 relays doesn't work

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I have the schematics below in which one of the relays work fine but the other doesn't, from design perspective they are the same!

The relay at the bottom is the one that is not working:

[image]

And this is the board layout:

[image]

I replaced the relay but it still doesn't work - all components are new.

Measured the output of the nodeMCU and it reports 3.x Volt which seems fine to me.

The code is not the problem as it works with the ready relay module connected to the nodemcu similar to this one:

[Relay module](https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=4Dws9bX1&id=06818E45360567D14D9EBD70C67DD9D4C2DED58A&thid=OIP.4Dws9bX1GTbzNk6ltVS9wwHaHa&mediaurl=https%3a%2f%2fth.bing.com%2fth%2fid%2fR.e03c2cf5b5f51936f3364ea5b554bdc3%3frik%3ditXewtTZfcZwvQ%26riu%3dhttp%253a%252f%252fosoyoo.com%252fwp-content%252fuploads%252f2017%252f08%252fQQ%25e5%259b%25be%25e7%2589%258720170828150350-768x768.jpg%26ehk%3dMPpxYaVjbqq%252bdtqjLbi6ojL3C1R8I8%252fN7YvoS87SWlc%253d%26risl%3d%26pid%3dImgRaw%26r%3d0&exph=768&expw=768&q=1+relay+module&simid=608014163944944118&FORM=IRPRST&ck=9F9AA5ADE3E80AAB5B8AF426CB491F2D&selectedIndex=8&qpvt=1+relay+module&ajaxhist=0&ajaxserp=0)

Please help in case you can see a problem in the board/schematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the transistor pinout is wrong, 2N3904 are emitter, base, collector but looks like you have base collector emitter.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Will test this out and in case I face a problem I will post back  in the meantime I will mark this as resolved thank you so much!